# Getting "Multiple-step operation generated errors" In ASP Classic Using Merged Data Set Function

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

I am using a function I read about [here](http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/classic-asp-merge-multiply-recordsets-into-single-recordset-169622.html) to merge a series of recordsets that are generated by a stored procedure that is called in a loop. I have used this function before in other stored procedure cases and it has never produced this problem.
The research I did online points to basically one of two reasons:
1) I am trying to update or insert a date/time value that is not formatted correctly into a SQL Server 2005 table
2) I am trying to insert a, for example, `CHAR(60)` string into a `CHAR(50)` field.

Reason one is not applicable here since I am not using dates (in datetime format at least).
Reason two seemed to be the most likely issue. So I did a series of `Response.Write()` to spit out the `objField.Name`, `objField.Type`, `objField.ActualSize`, and if it was a numeric field the `objField.Precision` and `objField.NumericScale`.

Let us say that the stored SQL procedure is called twice as I am querying for values that are occurring in the same time frame but 2 different states. The loop I have in the ASP page does a For Each on the state in the state list and calls the stored procedure for each of the elements in the state list. I then call the MergeRecordSets function so it combines the 2 results into one. The general rule is that the data types and sizes of the columns in each resultset must be the same. With my `Response.Write()` checks of each of the columns returned in the 2 data sets I have found that they are *identical*. Doing my checks I also found that it breaks on the first column that is a `NUMERIC` column. The previous columns it was OK with were all `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`.

Is there any other reason why this error would come up?

The following is how I am calling the record merger function. The `oQueryResult` is going to be the final output (the combined records). `objSingleRS` is the result set returned by the stored procedure.

```
If oQueryResult Is Nothing Then
    Set oQueryResult = objSingleRS
Else
    Set oQueryResult = MergeRecordSets(Array(oQueryResult, objSingleRS))
End If
```

Here is the merge function. The line in which the code breaks is marked below.

```
Function MergeRecordSets(arrRecordsets)
    Dim x, y, objCurrentRS
    Dim objMergedRecordSet, objField, blnExists
    Set objMergedRecordSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    For x=0 To UBound(arrRecordsets)
        Set objCurrentRS = arrRecordsets(x)

        For Each objField In objCurrentRS.Fields
            blnExists = False
            For y=0 To objMergedRecordSet.Fields.Count-1
                If LCase(objMergedRecordSet.Fields(y).Name) = Lcase(objField.Name) Then
                    blnExists = True : Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Not(blnExists) Then
                objMergedRecordSet.Fields.Append objField.Name, objField.Type, objField.DefinedSize
                'objMergedRecordSet.Fields(objMergedRecordset.Fields.Count-1).Attributes = 32 'adFldIsNullable
            End If
        Next
    Next

    objMergedRecordSet.Open

    For x=0 To UBound(arrRecordsets)
        Set objCurrentRS = arrRecordsets(x)

        Do Until objCurrentRS.EOF
            objMergedRecordSet.AddNew
            For Each objField In objCurrentRS.Fields
                If Not(IsNull(objField.Value)) Then
                    'Response.Write(objField.Name & "<br>")
                    'Response.Write(objField.Type & "<br>")
                    objMergedRecordSet.Fields(objField.Name).Value = objField.Value 'Here is where it throws the Error.
                End If
            Next
            objCurrentRS.MoveNext
        Loop
    Next

    objMergedRecordSet.MoveFirst
    Set MergeRecordSets = objMergedRecordSet
End Function
```

Here is the full error message returned:

```
Microsoft Cursor Engine error '80040e21'

Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.

/includes/funcs/Common.asp, line 4109
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you have `numeric` columns, but you never set the `Precision` and `NumericScale` properties when you create the new Field in `objMergedRecordSet`.  You need to set these properties for `adNumeric` and `adDecimal` fields.

```
objMergedRecordSet.Fields.Append objField.Name, objField.Type, objField.DefinedSize
With objMergedRecordSet.Fields(objField.Name)
    .Precision = objField.Precision
    .NumericScale = objField.NumericScale
End With
```

Comment: Yep, that was the fix we added back in August. I never came back to update this answer. For your effort I will give you the answer check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are not trying to put a NULL into a column that will not accept a NULL value. There is also the possibility of a type mismatch to cause this error so make sure you are passing a numeric value. 
- Freddo